# Exclusive touch in Flutter FlameGame

Tags: flutter, flame

I am developing a game in Flutter using Flame (`FlameGame`). There are multiple draggable components on the screen but I want to limit the user to only being able to drag one at a time.

I understand that I can do this by overridding the `DragCallbacks` with some sort of currently dragging logic. But I wondered if there was a built in/simpler way to do this. For example, iOS has [`exclusiveTouch`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622453-exclusivetouch)

The component I'm dragging is an `SvgComponent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'd have to keep track of it yourself since there isn't any method exposed to know whether there is another drag going on currently.

```dart
class YourGame extends FlameGame {
  int activeDrags = 0;

  ...
}

class YourComponent extends ... with DragCallbacks, HasGameReference<YourGame> {
  void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
    game.activeDrags++;
    if(game.activeDrags > 1) {
      return;
    }
    // Your logic
  }

  void onDragUpdate(DragUpdateEvent event) {
    if(game.activeDrags > 1) {
      return;
    }
    // Your logic
  }

  void onDragEnd(DragEndEvent event) {
    game.activeDrags--;
  }
}
```

This seems like an area we definitely could make more user friendly, if you file an enhancement issue on [our GitHub](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame) I'll look into it when I have time.

Comment: the draggable components are siblings not children. Think of a chess board and not being able to drag the queen and the king at the same time

Comment: Aah, I see what you mean, since _records isn't exposed in the `MultiDragDispatcher` you'd have to keep track of it yourself. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Great thanks. Issue added https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues/2726